# MODIFY TABLE of type ANY TABLE from field-symbol of type ANY

Tags: abap

I have a generic table of type "any table" and I'm trying to modify some entries in there, in this way:

```
  LOOP AT ct_data INTO <fs_data>.
    ASSIGN COMPONENT 'KEY' OF STRUCTURE <fs_data> TO <fs_feld_fu_key>.
    IF <fs_feld_fu_key> IS ASSIGNED.
      IF <fs_feld_fu_key> = <fs_mci_items>-parent_key.
        ASSIGN COMPONENT 'ZZ_CHANGED_FIELD' OF STRUCTURE <fs_data>  TO <fs_feld_walzzyk>.
        IF <fs_feld_walzzyk> IS ASSIGNED.
          <fs_feld_walzzyk> = <fs_mci_items>-zz_changed_field.
          MODIFY TABLE ct_data FROM <fs_data>.
        ENDIF.
      ENDIF.
    ENDIF.
  ENDLOOP.
```

Field-Symbols are all having the type "any".

Everything in this code woks just fine, BUT after this line:

```
MODIFY TABLE ct_data FROM <fs_data>.
```

I get SY_SUBRC = 4 and the table will not be modified. Does anybody have some ideas or tips? What am I doing wrong in this case?

Full code:

```
    DATA: rt_data TYPE REF TO data,
      ls_key  TYPE /bobf/s_frw_key,
      lt_key  TYPE /bobf/t_frw_key.
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_data>         TYPE any,
               <fs_feld_fu_key>  TYPE any,
               <fs_feld_walzzyk> TYPE any.


CREATE DATA rt_data LIKE LINE OF ct_data.
ASSIGN rt_data->* TO <fs_data>.

IF <fs_data> IS ASSIGNED.
  LOOP AT ct_data INTO <fs_data>.
    ASSIGN COMPONENT 'fu_key' OF STRUCTURE <fs_data> TO <fs_feld_fu_key>.
    IF <fs_feld_fu_key> IS ASSIGNED.
      ls_key-key = <fs_feld_fu_key>.
      APPEND ls_key TO lt_key.
    ENDIF.
  ENDLOOP.
ENDIF.


/scmtms/cl_tor_helper_read=>get_tor_data(
  EXPORTING
    it_root_key          = lt_key
  IMPORTING
    et_mci_items         = DATA(lt_mci_items)
).


LOOP AT lt_mci_items ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_mci_items>).
  LOOP AT ct_data INTO <fs_data>.
    ASSIGN COMPONENT 'FU_KEY' OF STRUCTURE <fs_data> TO <fs_feld_fu_key>.
    IF <fs_feld_fu_key> IS ASSIGNED.
      IF <fs_feld_fu_key> = <fs_mci_items>-parent_key.
        ASSIGN COMPONENT 'ZZ_CHANGED_FIELD' OF STRUCTURE <fs_data>  TO <fs_feld_walzzyk>.
        IF <fs_feld_walzzyk> IS ASSIGNED.
          <fs_feld_walzzyk> = <fs_mci_items>-zz_walzzyklus.
          MODIFY TABLE ct_data FROM <fs_data>.
        ENDIF.
      ENDIF.
    ENDIF.
  ENDLOOP.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: I might overlook something, but I don't get why do you need the MODIFY TABLE ... line at all. You use field symbols, which means the 'ZZ_CHANGE_FIELD' field of internal table CT_DATA will be changed directly through the field symbol assignments. Can you just remove the MODIFY TABLE line and see in debugging what happens?

Comment: That's exactly what I have done first. I also was sure, that I don't need MODIFY TABLE in this case, but even <fs_data> get updated with the right data. The ct_data does not get updated. That's why I've tried MODIFY TABLE.

Comment: @dyz if you remove the line "MODIFY TABLE", your code looks correct. Just be careful with one thing: after `ASSIGN ... TO <fs>`, testing `IF <fs> IS ASSIGNED` may be an error if at the same time the assignment was erroneous AND <fs> was previously assigned. Just check your full code (maybe you have more lines?). If that's the case, then replace the `IF <fs> IS ASSIGNED` with `IF sy-subrc = 0.`

Comment: @SandraRossi I just adjusted my code in the way you wrote and also have deleted MODIFY TABLE. 
There is no error at all and the field in the <fs_data> will be updated properly. But still no changes in CT_DATA. I really don't understand why...

Comment: I forgot to say that it "may be an error" because in case ASSIGN fails, the field symbol remains unchanged (so it remains assigned if it was previously assigned).

Answer (score 3):

`<fs_data>` doesn't point to `ct_data`. It points to a new memory area that you create in the very beginning. Remove this and declare the field symbol inline to get a pointer to the actual output:

```
DATA: rt_data TYPE REF TO data,
      ls_key  TYPE /bobf/s_frw_key,
      lt_key  TYPE /bobf/t_frw_key.
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <fs_feld_fu_key>  TYPE any,
               <fs_feld_walzzyk> TYPE any.


IF <fs_data> IS ASSIGNED.
  LOOP AT ct_data ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_data>).
    ASSIGN COMPONENT 'fu_key' OF STRUCTURE <fs_data> TO <fs_feld_fu_key>.
    IF <fs_feld_fu_key> IS ASSIGNED.
      ls_key-key = <fs_feld_fu_key>.
      APPEND ls_key TO lt_key.
    ENDIF.
  ENDLOOP.
ENDIF.


/scmtms/cl_tor_helper_read=>get_tor_data(
  EXPORTING
    it_root_key          = lt_key
  IMPORTING
    et_mci_items         = DATA(lt_mci_items)
).


LOOP AT lt_mci_items ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_mci_items>).
  LOOP AT ct_data ASSIGNING <fs_data>.
    ASSIGN COMPONENT 'FU_KEY' OF STRUCTURE <fs_data> TO <fs_feld_fu_key>.
    IF <fs_feld_fu_key> IS ASSIGNED.
      IF <fs_feld_fu_key> = <fs_mci_items>-parent_key.
        ASSIGN COMPONENT 'ZZ_CHANGED_FIELD' OF STRUCTURE <fs_data>  TO <fs_feld_walzzyk>.
        IF <fs_feld_walzzyk> IS ASSIGNED.
          <fs_feld_walzzyk> = <fs_mci_items>-zz_walzzyklus.
        ENDIF.
      ENDIF.
    ENDIF.
  ENDLOOP.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Oh gosh, well seen :) that `LOOP ... INTO <fs>` should be warned + pragma by the code parser/syntax checker because it's 99% of the time incorrect (we almost always use: `LOOP ... ASSIGNING <fs>`)

Answer (score 0):

`<fs_data>` is a pointer to a row in `ct_data`. You are trying to modify the table from itself. The `sy-subrc = 4` simply states that there is nothing to change.

As JozsefSzikszai points out in his comment, you don't need the `MODIFY TABLE` at all. Simply change the values in `<fs_data>` directly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Florian.
The problem is that <fs_data> has a type "any", so I cannot use <fs_data>-ZZ_CHANGED_FIELD = <fs_mci_items>-zz_changed_field

Comment: I just updated my question with full version of my code, so it is more clear what I am doing.

Comment: @florian because <fs_data> is of type ANY, "simply change [...] <fs_data>-zz_changed_field" is incorrect; anyway this sentence can be omitted because your comment  "you don't need the MODIFY TABLE" is sufficient (or say "the line MODIFY TABLE is useless because the line is already changed owing to the field symbol changed").

Comment: @SandraRossi exactly. The type ANY is my problem. Otherwise it would be quite easy peace of code. What I dont understand is why my table does not get updated even all assignments work fine in debugger

Comment: @dyz you may check immediately that the ASSIGN does a change of the internal table by using a **watchpoint** on the internal table, the debugger will stop every time the internal table is changed. If it doesn't change, it means that the source field has the same value. If you're unsure what's going on, you may gain confidence by changing the field symbol value manually with the debugger to a dummy value just to verify it reflects in the internal table.

Comment: @SandraRossi: thanks for the tip with the watchpoint! I used watchpoint on ct_data and indeed the debugger stops every time, but I don't see that the values in the column will be changed...
I asking myself how can it happend?

Comment: My other answer explains why.